# Skip a special character '-' on a Javascript function call

Tags: javascript

This is the code I'm using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<header>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">  
<!--  
function pass(InputValue){  

    if(document.getElementById('storevalues').value == false ) {document.getElementById('storevalues').innerHTML = InputValue;}

            else {
                document.getElementById('storevalues').innerHTML += " ,"+InputValue;    
            } 
}     
//-->  
</script>

</header>

<body>

<form name="first">  
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="storevalues"></textarea>

<input type="checkbox" id="DAVIDHU" value="DAVIDHU" onclick="pass(document.first.DAVIDHU.value)">

<input type="checkbox"  id="CHARLES-STEVEN" value="CHARLES-STEVEN" onclick="pass(document.first.CHARLES-STEVEN.value)">
</form> 

</form>

</section>

</body>
```

When you check the first checkbox the value of that checkbox goes to the textarea this case is DAVIDHU,
but when you check the second checkbox, this case is CHARLES-STEVEN the value doesn't go to the textarea, I believe it has something to go with the special character '-' I tried escap using back slash exp : CHARLES-STEVEN but it didn't work, the thing is that I have so many user with a combined first and last name with "-"

any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can only use dot notation with valid identifiers.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) `CHARLES-STEVEN` is not a valid identifier because – you guessed it – of the dash. So switch to [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
document.first['CHARLES-STEVEN'].value
```

Comment: You are soo coool! and this works perfect!!! Thanks a lot!!! the system suggest that I can accept an answer in 5 minutes and I will.
Thanks again!!